# AngularJS Material - Issues with ng-model and ng-change accessing the same object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular-material and I have an md-switch item whose model is being set based on the value in a JS object. The challenge I'm having is, when the user clicks the switch, I don't want to change the object value directly - instead, I want to execute a function that is in the object that changes the value for me.

In the code (or JSFiddle below) you can see that the toggle state never changes.

This is a trivial example, so it doesn't go into the reason why, but is something like this possible?

Here is sample code

HTML

```
<div class="inset switchdemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="SwitchDemoCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-switch ng-model="data.state" aria-label="Switch 2" class="md-primary" ng-change="data.change()">
    {{ data.state }}
  </md-switch>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
.controller('SwitchDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    state: true,
    change: function() {
      this.state = !this.state;
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wx8s709z/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that it never changes but you changes it two times.
First time it changes when you click and second time you change it by your function. So if you comment your code into call function you'll see that all works.

**ng-change is event that indicates you that your value is changed and then you can call another function with it's value**, using only $scope.data.state

Comment: Yes - good point, I can see that. But is there a way for me to keep the model linked to the object property but only execute the function when the toggle is made? (I.e. only execute the model change via the function?)

Comment: @darudude yes you can make a trick in that function, for example
with ng-change you can call your function (certainly with changed value) if all right you'll keep new value otherwise you can invert it by restoring your original code, data.state = !data.state